# Kafka ISR Shrinked and doesn't Expand

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-topic

I have a Kafka Cluster of 3 nodes with 1 ZK and 1 Broker each.

`Kafka version 0.10.1.1.`

Each Topic has `replication-factor=3` and `min.insync.replicas=2`. We have checked by issuing `--describe` thereafter, that the Topic(s) were successfully created with correct `replication-factor` and `ISR`.

**I can see after a while few of the Topics shrunk their ISR into a Single Leader.**

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper zk1:2181,zk2:2181,zk3:2181 --topic topic1
Topic:topic1  PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:
        Topic: topic1 Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1

/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper zk1:2181,zk2:2181,zk3:2181 --topic topic2
Topic:topic2  PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:
        Topic: topic2 Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
```

When I connect to `zk Shell`. I can see all Nodes are up and the `controller` is in `broker:2`

```
/opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh --describe --zookeeper zk1:2181,zk2:2181,zk3:2181
ls /brokers/ids
[0,1,2]

get /controller
{"version":1,"brokerid":2,"timestamp":"1531740996571"}
```

Even if I try to restart the Brokers (Only brokers or along with zookeepers), the Topics don't expand.

Any advice is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the topic's descriptions, it looks like these topics were created with a replication factor of 1:

```
ReplicationFactor:1
```

Having `default.replication.factor=2` and `min.insync.replicas=2` set in the broker configs does not prevent the creation of topics with replication factor=1.

To fix that, you can [increase the replication factor](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_increase_replication_factor) of these topics using the `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` tool.

To prevent this happening, you can use the [Create Topic](http://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/server/policy/CreateTopicPolicy.html) and [Alter Config](http://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/server/policy/AlterConfigPolicy.html)  Policies to reject topics with an invalid replication factor.

Comment: Thanks. Will check. I have checked the `history` of the commands and the `--create` clearly showed `replication-factor=3`.

Comment: Command used for create: `/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper zk1:2181,zk2:2181,zk3:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --config min.insync.replicas=2 --topic topic1`

Comment: Can you please guide me to some usages of Create Topic Policy and Alter Config Policy?

Comment: These are not available in 0.10.1. The create topic policy was added in 0.10.2 and alter configs in 0.11. Also policies are only used when creating/altering topics via the Kafka Admin APIs.

If you're interested in using them, upgrade to a newer release, check the javadoc links from my answer and read the configuration description for `create.topic.policy.class.name` and `alter.config.policy.class.name` from http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs